# Token + project provisioning = Insufficient privileges

Tags: sonarqube

I call MSBuild.SonarQube.Scanner.exe with a token in *sonar.login* and a string in *sonar.branch*.

The execution fails with the following error:

```
13:42:03.817 INFO  - Analysis report generated in 271ms, dir size=497 KB
13:42:04.624 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 806ms, zip size=212 KB
13:42:04.624 DEBUG - Upload report
13:42:05.125 DEBUG - POST 403 http://192.168.18.21:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=XYZ&projectName=Its%20XYZ&projectBranch=lala | time=501ms
13:42:05.127 INFO  - Analysis report generated in C:\Develop\XYZ\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\batch-report
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 41.303s
Final Memory: 9M/270M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: Insufficient privileges
```

The token is generated for a user called *Scanner* and the user is in the group *sonar-users*.
He has global permissions for *Execute Analysis*, *Execute Preview Analysis* and *Provision Projects*.

If I execute the same for an existing project it works. It seems the token is not allowed to provision a project. Is this possible?

Edit: *SonarQube 5.3* and *MSBuild.SonarQube.Scanner 1.1*

Edit 2: We use LDAP (AD) authentification

Edit 3: Last entry in access.log

```
[02/Mrz/2016:18:44:43 +0100] "POST /api/ce/submit?projectKey=XYZ&projectName=Its XYZ&projectBranch=lala HTTP/1.1" 403 46 "-" "SonarQubeRunner/2.4"
```

---

**Further investigations:**

MSBuild.SonarQube.Scanner.exe is called via command line like:

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe /key:XYZ /name:"Its XYZ" /version:1.0.0.0 /d:sonar.branch=lala /d:sonar.scm.provider=git /d:sonar.host.url=http://192.168.18.21:9000 /d:sonar.login=<token>
```

This does not work.

But if I place the *sonar.login* property within the *SonarQube.Analytics.xml* it works. So does MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe command line ignores */d:sonar.login*?

Edit: Currently *Anyone* was allowed to *execute analysis*, so maybe thats the reason why all other tasks worked except the provisioning.

Comment: Your log is too short, we can't know where it fails. Can you please post more of the log, and if possible post it with debug mode activated? (you can post it on pastebin.org - it will be better)

Comment: Thanks Fabrice. I try to get some more log.
Btw: Are there some docs about the api/ce/submit?

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam Here are the logs (sonar.log+access.log in debugmode) http://pastebin.com/LHBQupRQ Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: I also executed MSBuild Sonar Scanner in Debug mode and extended the error message at the top.

Comment: I added further investigations to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems I have to pass the token */d:sonar.login=* to the call of *MSBuild.SonarQube.Scanner.exe end* too - because it's not defined within the SonarQube.Analytics.xml. Sounds pretty clear now -.-

Comment: yep, the MSBuild Scanner doesn't persist credentials on disk for security reasons, so you need to pass these both to the `begin` and `end` step